# How it replace all database functionality with an api in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and have been tasked with re-tooling an existing app.  Currently, my biggest obstacle is that instead of a database, all data will be accessed through an external API.  I have created several other apps this way and very comfortable working with the external API. But in order NOT to entirely re-write this new project I need to figure out a way to replace the old database with the new API.

I have found https://github.com/jenssegers/model which seems to have the functionality I need to replace Eloquent (which appears to be all about database interactions) with model that transforms API consumptions to be able to use Eloquent functions like first, last, with, etc.

The old database has a table called "StaticPages' the so I have created a new model extending the jenssegers/model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

// use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \Jenssegers\Model\Model as EloquentLike;

class StaticPage extends EloquentLike
{
    protected $hidden = [];
    protected $casts = [
        'sampleId' => 'string',
        'ID' => 'string',
        'CreateDate' => 'datetime',
        'UpdateDate' => 'datetime',
        'Status' => 'string',
        'Page' => 'string',
        'SiteVar' => 'string',
        'Content' => 'string',

    ];
    protected $guarded = [
        'sampleId',
        'ID',
    ];
    protected $fillable = [
        'CreateDate',
        'UpdateDate',
        'Status',
        'Page',
        'SiteVar',
        'Content',
    ];


}
```

but now I am unsure how to go about pulling the data from the external API into this model (is it a handler, a repository, or what).  The although the data coming from the API has all the same fields as the database it is no longer a "table" called "StaticPages" it is now a dataStore called "3827".

So I am trying to refactor so that I can get the existing call :

```
$sp = StaticPage::where('group', '=', $group)->orderBy('page', 'asc')->paginate(20);
```

to return the same records it queries the API as it world from the previous database.

Does anyone know if any resources I can use to figure this out.  When I google how to use an API as a database in Laravel I can find a ton of information on how to create an API with Laravel but nothing (other than it is possible) about how to replace the database with an API.

Comment: Without the API details, it's not really possible to answer.  But you can for sure create a class that has a static method `where` but you have to return `$this` for method chaining.

Comment: What API details would be helpful to answer this question? If you tell me I can post them.  I am not trying to figure out this specific call but rather how to get the API to replace the database so that all (or at least vast majority) the current calls will work.

Comment: Well you will have to "wrap" or "beautify" the API.  Basically you need to make a class to translate from laravel ( something I don't use) to your API calls.  For [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8380ba40e992cd2f344e105e74fec3395cf85675)  PS it outputs nothing, but that's good no errors.